# Derivation of the S-matrix/Dyson's formula from David Tong's lecture notes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, scattering, s-matrix-theory

I am studying quantum field theory from [David Tong's lecture notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf) and I am stuck at a particular place.

In Page 52., under the heading *3.1.1 Dyson's Formula*, Tong introduces an unitary operator 
$U(t, t_0) = T \exp(-i\int_{t_0}^{t}H_I(t') dt')$

He then introduces the usual definition of time ordered products and goes on to expand $U(t,t_0)$. I am not able to follow how he expanded the time ordered product of operators in the second-order term of the Taylor expansion of the exponential. In particular, **I am unable to follow the limits being used and why why both integrals are being put in the front.** Should we not get product of two integrals involving $H_I$?

The expansion of $U(t,t_0)$ is given by

$1 - i\int_{t_0}^{t}dt'H_I(t') + \frac{-i^2}{2}[\int_{t_0}^{t}dt'\int_{t'}^{t}dt''H_I(t'')H_I(t')+\int_{t_0}^{t}dt'\int_{t_0}^{t'}dt''H_I(t')H_I(t'')]+... $

Link to Course Page - [David Tong: Lectures on Quantum Field Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the second order (for example), the expansion of the time evolution operator is:
$$U(t,t_0) = T\exp\left(-i\int_{t_0}^tH_I(t')dt'\right)=1-i\int_{t_0}^tH_I(t_1)dt_1+\frac{(-i)^2}{2}T(\int_{t_0}^tH_I(t')dt')^2$$ 
You can see that the second order term could be rewritten as:
$$\int_{t_0}^tH_I(t_1)dt_1\int_{t_0}^tH_I(t_2)dt_2$$
or 
$$\int_{t_0}^tH_I(t_2)dt_2\int_{t_0}^tH_I(t_1)dt_1$$
depending on the value of $t_1$ and $t_2$ (Remember that the interacting Hamiltonians at different times do not commute with each other). With the aid of the time-order product, we can safely write:
\begin{align}
\frac{(-i)^2}{2}T(\int_{t_0}^tH_I(t')dt')^2=\frac{(-i)^2}{2}T\int_{t_0}^tH_I(t_1)dt_1\int_{t_0}^tH_I(t_2)dt_2 \\
=\frac{(-i)^2}{2}T\int_{t_0}^t\int_{t_0}^tH_I(t_1)H_I(t_2)dt_1dt_2
\end{align}
The expression in the end of your post can be received from this by a change of variable, which you can see in several texts.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. It seems very obvious right now. Expanding your last expression according to the definition of time ordered products gives us the desired expression.

Comment: @Lê Dũng, I still don't get how the $t'$ can be in the differential and also on the limit of the integral. Could you clarify that?

Comment: @xihiro For the integral limit, the appearance of T-product means there can be 2 cases $t_1>t_2$ and $t_2>t_1$ . This is why we have 2 integrals for the second-order term with 2 limits as in the question.  For your first question, sorry I don't understand your question.Could you clarify it?

Comment: Can you explain why we replace t with t'  , t''  , t"' etc in limit of integral , can any one explain @Lê Dũng